# R Roxygen @examples /Example/foo_bar not found

Tags: r-package, roxygen2

I am creating an R package and can't run the examples when using `devtools::load_all()`
I always get **/Example/function_name not found.**
Currently, I add, commit, and push changes to github, install the library with `devtools::install_github()` and run my examples. There must be a smarter way...
My Roxygen documentation looks like this:

```
#' @examples
#' foo <- example_function(bar)
```

How can I test run my examples locally in the project?